# utf-8 in uppercase?

Tags: c#, xml, formatting

This is more of a cosmetic change that I wanted to make and I was wondering how could I make the generated xml file with UTF-8 uppercase instead of utf-8 lowercase ?

```
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = "\t";

        XmlWriter writeXML = XmlWriter.Create("test_file.xml", settings);
        writeXML.WriteStartDocument(false);
        writeXML.WriteComment(fileLicense);
        writeXML.WriteStartElement("templates");
        writeXML.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        writeXML.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", null, "test_file.xsd");
        writeXML.WriteEndElement();
        writeXML.WriteEndDocument();
        writeXML.Close();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found [this blog post](http://www.distribucon.com/2008/01/29/MakingTheEncodingPropertyUpperCaseDuringXmlSerialization.aspx). Seems it is what you want.

```
public class UpperCaseUTF8Encoding : UTF8Encoding
{
  // Code from a blog http://www.distribucon.com/blog/CategoryView,category,XML.aspx
  //
  // Dan Miser - Thoughts from Dan Miser
  // Tuesday, January 29, 2008 
  // He used the Reflector to understand the heirarchy of the encoding class
  //
  //      Back to Reflector, and I notice that the Encoding.WebName is the property used to
  //      write out the encoding string. I now create a descendant class of UTF8Encoding.
  //      The class is listed below. Now I just call XmlTextWriter, passing in
  //      UpperCaseUTF8Encoding.UpperCaseUTF8 for the Encoding type, and everything works
  //      perfectly. - Dan Miser

  public override string WebName
  {
    get { return base.WebName.ToUpper(); }
  }

  public static UpperCaseUTF8Encoding UpperCaseUTF8
  {
    get
    {
      if (upperCaseUtf8Encoding == null) {
        upperCaseUtf8Encoding = new UpperCaseUTF8Encoding();
      }
      return upperCaseUtf8Encoding;
    }
  }  

  private static UpperCaseUTF8Encoding upperCaseUtf8Encoding = null;
}
```

To use this custom encoding you need to use an XMLTextWriter as the destination to the XDocument Save method.

```
// This section not shown in the blog

var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlDocNm); //This is your xml path value 
// Changes to XML Document here

// .Net writes the XML declaration using lower case utf-8.
//  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
// It is not suppesed to matter but NiceForm expects the delcaration to be uppercase.
//  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
// We are using a XMLWriter with a custom Encoding to captialize the UTF

// Set various options to retrive the desired output
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {
  Encoding = new UpperCaseUTF8Encoding(), // Key setting option for this example

  NewLineHandling = System.Xml.NewLineHandling.Replace,
  NewLineOnAttributes = true,
  Indent = true                           // Generate new lines for each element
};

using (var xmlWriter =XmlTextWriter.Create(xmlDocNm, settings)) {
  xDoc.Save(xmlWriter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your code in an Xml class I wrote. It does other stuff too, such as allow to output in UTF-8 or UTF-16 and make pretty or linearize the Xml.
http://www.rhyous.com/2015/04/07/an-xml-class-to-linearize-xml-make-pretty-xml-and-encoding-in-utf-8-or-utf-16/

Answer (score -1):

```
writeXML.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some explanation why do think your proposed solution might help the OP. Do not post just code without explanation.