# UTF-8 encoding in uppercase while creating XML with dotnet core

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, linq-to-xml, declaration

This solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/4291369/12870838 for .Net Framework no longer works in Dotnet Core. Tested with Dotent Core 3.1.101 and .Net Framework 4.7.1

Is there a more elegant solution than this workaround?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547816/12870838

In the XmlEncodedRawTextWriter on line 242, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.Xml/src/System/Xml/Core/XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.cs#L242,
 a different instance is used than I set in XmlWriterSettings. 
I think the problem is in line 175.

Is there another way for Dotnet Core to write the XML declaration UTF-8 in uppercase?

This is a requirement for Apple Plist files.

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XDocumentType("plist", "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN", "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd", null),
    new XElement("plist"))
{
    Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", string.Empty)
};


var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    //Encoding = new UTF8Encoding()
    Encoding = new UpperCaseUTF8Encoding()
};

using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("demo.xml", settings))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{xmlWriter.Settings.Encoding.WebName}, {settings.Encoding.WebName}");
    doc.Save(xmlWriter);
}
```

```
public class UpperCaseUTF8Encoding : UTF8Encoding
{
    public UpperCaseUTF8Encoding() : this(false)
    {
    }

    public UpperCaseUTF8Encoding(bool encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier) : this(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier, false)
    {
    }

    public UpperCaseUTF8Encoding(bool encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier, bool throwOnInvalidBytes) : base(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier, throwOnInvalidBytes)
    {
    }

    public override string WebName => base.WebName.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```